# How to create a dictionary structure in json.net using json to linq

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I am using Json.NET to create a definition of json whose structure may change. I am therefore unable to simply serialize a class and am creating the structure on the fly using Json to Linq. I am having issues creating the following structure using JObject, JArray, JProperty, etc

```
 {
  'external_id':'UNIQUE_ID_222222222',
  'firstname':'John',
  'lastname':'Smith',
  'customFields':
      {
        'custom1':'custom1 val',
        'custom2':'custom2 val',
        'custom3"':'custom3 val'
      }
  }
```

I tried using the following code:

```
Dim json As New JArray()
Dim jsonObj As New JObject( _
            New JProperty("external_id", "UNIQUE_ID_222222222"),
            New JProperty("firstname", "John"),
            New JProperty("lastname", "Smith"))

Dim jsonCustomFields As New JArray
Dim jsonCustomObject As New JObject

jsonCustomFields.Add(jsonCustomObject)

For Each field In CustomFieldList
    jsonCustomObject.Add(New JProperty(field.Label, field.Value))
Next    

jsonObj.Add(New JProperty("customFields", jsonCustomFields))
json.Add(jsonContrib)
```

However when I do this I get a different pattern that was not accepted by the webservice

```
{[
  {
    "external_id": "50702",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smithson",
    "customFields": [
      {
        "custom1":"custom1 val",
        "custom2":"custom2 val",
        "custom3":"custom3 val"
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

I thought that I should be adding properties directly to the JArray but doing this causes a run time exception.

I have seen a similar pattern that is created when you deserialize a Dictionary(String, String) object but I don't really want to add my custom fields to a dictionary only to then deserialize them. It must be possible to create them using the above notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a `JArray`, instead use `JObject`

Following code is C# but you will be able to figure out

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
jObject.Add(new JProperty("external_id", "UNIQUE_ID_222222222"));
jObject.Add(new JProperty( "firstname", "John" ));
jObject.Add(new JProperty( "lastname", "Smith" ));

JObject customFields = new JObject();
//Your loop
customFields.Add( "custom1", "custom1 val" );
customFields.Add( "custom2", "custom2 val" );
customFields.Add( "custom3", "custom3 val" );

jObject.Add( new JProperty( "customFields", customFields ) );
```

Let me know this works or not

Comment: Thank you. That does work. I guess I got confused when I saw the list of iterated properties and automatically assumed "array"